# No metadata for "LookupType" was found. EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "LookupType" was found

Tags: webpack, nestjs, typeorm, monorepo, nx.dev

I am trying to create a backend using NestJS with nx mono repo and I am getting this error
No metadata for "LookupType" was found. EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "LookupType" was found.

error detail:
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "LookupType" was found.
at DataSource.getMetadata (/Users/ramazan/Source/crossborder-codebase/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:438:30)
at Repository.get metadata [as metadata] (/Users/ramazan/Source/crossborder-codebase/src/repository/Repository.ts:53:40)
at Repository.findOne (/Users/ramazan/Source/crossborder-codebase/src/repository/Repository.ts:577:42)
at PostgreSqlGenericRepository. (/Users/ramazan/Source/crossborder-codebase/dist/apps/api/webpack:/src/frameworks/data-services/postgresql/postgresql-generic-repository.ts:55:43)
at Generator.next ()
at /Users/ramazan/Source/crossborder-codebase/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:167:75
at new Promise ()
at Object.__awaiter (/Users/ramazan/Source/crossborder-codebase/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:163:16)
at PostgreSqlGenericRepository.get (/Users/ramazan/Source/crossborder-codebase/dist/apps/api/main.js:2476:24)
at LookupTypeUseCases. (/Users/ramazan/Source/crossborder-codebase/dist/apps/api/webpack:/src/use-cases/lookup-type/lookuptype.use-case.ts:38:53)

- typeorm.config.ts is empty
- nx using webpack I using default config.
- The project build successfully and extract main.js and main.map.js

project directory structure with nx(mono repo)
[image]

configuration.module.ts

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  inject: [ConfigService],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
    password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
    synchronize: true,
  }),
```

Comment: Which typeorm version are you using?

Comment: I solved the problem as changed build config "executor": "@nrwl/js:tsc" in project app.json. thanks bro

Comment: for me, adding autoLoadEntities: true, got it working.
autoLoadEntities: true,

useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
    password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
autoLoadEntities: true,
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
    synchronize: true,
  }),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as changed build config "executor": "@nrwl/js:tsc" in project.app.json

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding autoLoadEntities: true, got it working.

```
useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
    password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
 autoLoadEntities: true,
    entities: [__dirname + '/../**/**/*.entity.{ts,js}'],
    synchronize: true,
  }),
```